# Separating column string values with varying delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, split

I have a column in a dataframe that I want to split into two columns. The values in the column are strings with a players' name followed by their position. Because players have different numbers of names, this becomes a bigger issue.

For example:

- 1 name: `Jorginho Defensive Midfield`
- 2 names: `Heung-min Son Left Winger`
- 3 names: `Bilal El Khannouss Attacking Midfield`

The desired output would be:

```
Player              Position
Jorginho            Defensive Midfield
Heung-min Son       Left Winger
Bilal El Khannouss  Attacking Midfield
```

I believe this can be done by listing the player positions, however I don't know how to approach that problem. I tried separating using `split()` with a space character as the delimiter, but that doesn't work unfortunately.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player': ['Richarlison Centre-Forward',
                              'Heung-min Son Left Winger',
                              'Harry Wilson Right Winger',
                              'Bilal El Khannouss Attacking Midfield',
                              'Eduardo Camavinga Central Midfield',
                              'Jorginho Defensive Midfield',
                              'Lewis Patterson Centre-Back',
                              'Layvin Kurzawa Left-Back',
                              'Kyle Walker Right-Back',
                              'Jordan Pickford Goalkeeper']})

positions = ['Centre-Forward', 'Left Winger', 'Right Winger',
             'Attacking Midfield', 'Central Midfield', 'Defensive Midfield',
             'Centre-Back', 'Left-Back', 'Right-Back', 'Goalkeeper']
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can craft a regex.

```
import re
regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, positions))

df['Player'].str.extract(fr'(.*)\s*({regex})')
```

*NB. changed `'Central Midfielder'` to `'Central Midfield'` in the list of positions.*

Another approach **that does not require any list**, would be to extract the last 2 words (either separated by spaces, or a dash):

```
df['Player'].str.extract(r'(.*)\s(\w+(?:-|\s+)\w+)')
```

output:

```
                     0                   1
0         Richarlison       Centre-Forward
1       Heung-min Son          Left Winger
2        Harry Wilson         Right Winger
3  Bilal El Khannouss   Attacking Midfield
4   Eduardo Camavinga     Central Midfield
5            Jorginho   Defensive Midfield
6     Lewis Patterson          Centre-Back
7      Layvin Kurzawa            Left-Back
8         Kyle Walker           Right-Back
9     Jordan Pickford           Goalkeeper
```

Comment: Assign to new columns in the DataFrame: `df[['new_1', 'new_2']] = df['Player'].str.extract(...)` or if you want to drop the Player: `df[['new_1', 'new_2']] = df.pop('Player').str.extract(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use re.sub() function to delete the positions from the player list and then create another list of player. Here the positions are indexed with player so I don't use for loop for matching the position.

```
import re
player = [item for item in range(len(positions))]
for i in range(len(positions)):
    player[i]=re.sub(positions[i],'',str(df['Player'][i]))
d_frame = {'Player':player,'Position':positions}
df = pd.DataFrame(d_frame)
```

You can use it to make the new dataframe